# Interview question on stack

Tags: stack

recently my friend attended intv, he faced this question(intviewer made this up from my fren's answer to another question)
Say, we have option to use either 
1) recursion --> uses system stack, i think OS takes care of everything
2) use our own stack for only data part and get things done.
to fix something. Which one do you prefer? and why?
assume stack size wouldn't grow beyond 100.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the system stack. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: its not about re-inventing. i think he is expecting answer, performance point of view.

Comment: @user520959 - Performance is just one consideration. Unless the interviewer specifically mentions that it is the single most important consideration, in this case, i would agree with rubayeet too

Comment: @user520959 - Was the interviewer question 'Which would be faster'? Even so, how would you guarantee that a your own solution would be faster than using system stack?

Answer (score 1):

Function calls, while not really slow per se, do take non-zero time. Therefore an iterative solution can be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

More often thatn not, simplicity is better than a slight performance gain.

Dont overkill a solution, and loose maitainability/readability for 1ms if you are not going to use that 1ms.

Just remember that whatever clever little hack you put together has to be maintained (and proven to work first for that matter) where as many standard/system solutions are available, that has been proven. (see Reinventing the wheel).

If it is really system crytical that you reduce memory allocation and enhance performance, you have your work cut out for you, and be prepared to spend some time proving that your solution is better/faster and stable.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting to see the general preference for recursion on here, and a few who assume that the recursive implementation will necessarily be clearer or more maintainable... maybe, maybe not :-).

- recursion typically avoids an explicit loop
- recursion can sometimes simply use local variables inside the function to avoid a container storing results as they're calculated
- recursion can make it trivial to reverse the order in which sub-results are gathered
- recursion means there's a limit to the depth of information being processed, where-as often a loop implementation easily avoids this, or at least has memory requirements that more accurately reflect the data-processing needs

  - the more widely applicable you want your software to be, the more important it is to remove arbitrary limits (e.g. UNIX software like modern vim, less, GNU grep etc. make minimal assumptions about file/line/expression length and dynamically attempt whatever they're asked / many here will remember old editors and vendor-specific utilities e.g. one "celestial" company's grep that would never match results at the end of a too-long line, editors that SIGSEGVed, shutdown, corrupted or slowed down into uselessness on long lines or files)
- naive recursion can result in spectacularly inefficiently combined sub-results
- some people find recursion easier to understand, some find it harder - definitely it suits how we think about some problems better than others

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the algorithm. Small stack usage, system stack. Lot of stack needed, go on the heap. Stack size is limited by OS beyond which OS throws stackoverflow ;-) If algo uses more stack space then I would go with stack data structure and push the data on the heap

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think it deppends the problem...

The stack size, if I got your point, is not only what limits you from using one or another.

But wanting to use recursion... well, no bads, really, for the length of the stack, but I'd rather make my own solution.

Avoid recursion when you can. :)

Comment: recursion is not bad. besides, it can reduce implementation time.

Comment: it also depends on the machine, if a context switch takes 10ms on that machine then you should use your own stack

Answer (score 0):

Recursion may be the simplest way to solve a particular problem. An iterative solution can required more code and more opportunities for errors. The testing and maintenance cost may be greater than the performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first, use the system stack. That being said the language FORTH there are two system stacks. One is the return stack and the other is the parameters stack. This offers some nice  flexibility.